# Unnamed Window in Applescript

Tags: user-interface, scripting, window, applescript, itunes

I'm scripting iTunes with applescript using UI scripting. Depending on what I'm doing an iTunes notification will appear, at which point I need to handle it. The name of the window is AXWindow: "", and I can't seam to get applescript to handle it. I've tried using the literal "", I've tried defining a variable to "", I've tried both cases with escape characters, and I've tried getting the name of the frontmost process.

```
tell application "System Events"
     set processName to name of front window
end tell
tell button "whatever" of window processName
     click
end tell
```

But that comes up with "error "System Events got an error: Can't get window 1. Invalid Index."" Any help on this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
tell application "iTunes" to activate
tell application "System Events"
    tell process "iTunes"
        set xxx to first UI element whose role description is "dialog"
    end tell
end tell
```

Or to find them all:

```
tell application "iTunes" to activate
tell application "System Events"
    tell process "iTunes"
        set xxx to every UI element
    end tell
end tell
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, usually notifications or user dialogs will show up as the frontmost window and stay on top of the other windows of the same application until the user (or the script) clicks something.

Thus, the dialog window (if there is any) should be accessible via the specifier `window 1`. You can then further check if that really is the window you're interested in by reading its properties:

```
tell application "System Events" to tell application process "iTunes"
  properties of window 1
end tell
```

Comment: I thought the same thing, but I get an error telling me that window 1 is invalid